# Whether data recovery after flashing custom ROMs needs a copy of eMMC as a whole

Tags: backup, custom-roms, data-recovery

The common guide for Android data backup and recovery is to make a copy of userdata, while I noticed that after flashing CM ROM all my devices (Oppo Find 7 MSM and Meizu Meilan2 MTK) contents of `/dev/block` changed to `mmcblk0p` form and the path of "by-name" is also change to the same `/dev/block/platform/(related to chip)/by-name`, which is different from the guides I saw.

I want to try to recover the data before flashing, so I wonder whether it is sufficient to make separate copies of partitions. I don't know where is Android's GPT table or something that records partition change.

By the way, it seems that making copy separately is easier, is there a `dd` or pull method other than booting into download mode to copy as a whole?